# MySQL8 Binary installation - getting error msg "-bash: bin/mysql: Permission denied" after upgrading to 8.0.22

Tags: mysql-8.0

We have a MySQL 8 instance with Binary Installation. After upgrading to 8.0.22 (from 8.0.19) can't seem to connect using following cmd in CLI

```
bin/mysql -uusername -p
```

error msg -

```
-bash: bin/mysql: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug reported for this. Hope this helps someone.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101969